# Determine if an arbitrary machine is joined to a Active Directory domain?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I want to query Active Directory to see if an **arbitrary machine** (i.e. not just the local machine my code is running on) is joined using only the **machine name**

I know about `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain()` but this only tells me if the local machine is a member of a domain.

In my case I have a list of machine names and I want to determine which ones are joined and which ones are not.  Is there a way to do this?

#### Possible Approach

Here is a possible answer using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.  If there is no computer with a matching machine name in AD a null value will be returned.  However this approach is **not ideal** because it requires administrative credentials:

```
const string S_USER = "username";
const string S_PASS = "password";

static public ComputerPrincipal GetComputerInfo(string ComputerName)
{
    try
    {
        // enter AD settings  
        PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
            DOMAIN, S_USER, S_PASS);

        // create search user and add criteria
        ComputerPrincipal c = new ComputerPrincipal(AD);
        c.Name = ComputerName;

        // search for user  
        PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(c);
        ComputerPrincipal result = (ComputerPrincipal)search.FindOne();
        search.Dispose();

        return result;
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
    Console.Read();
    return null;
}
```

Is there an alternative approach that does not require administrative credentials?

Comment: That question is about determining the domain for the local machine not for a computer name.

Comment: Editing your questions to add additional details and clarifications is valuable.  However adding rants about why it is not a duplicate is not appropriate and you should comment/flag the post for attention in cases like this, I have edited the question to hopefully make the question clearly non-duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to determine it by its NETBIOS domain:

```
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int NetWkstaGetInfo(string server,
        int level,
        out IntPtr info);

[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int NetWkstaGetInfo(string server,
        int level,
        out IntPtr info);

    [DllImport("netapi32.dll")]
    static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr pBuf);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    class WKSTA_INFO_100
    {
        public int wki100_platform_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string wki100_computername;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string wki100_langroup;
        public int wki100_ver_major;
        public int wki100_ver_minor;
    }

    public static string GetMachineNetBiosDomain(string server)
    {
        IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;

        WKSTA_INFO_100 info;
        int retval = NetWkstaGetInfo(server, 100, out pBuffer);
        if (retval != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(retval);

        info = (WKSTA_INFO_100)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pBuffer, typeof(WKSTA_INFO_100));
        string domainName = info.wki100_langroup;
        NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
        return domainName;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly.. the OP has a list of machine names to test against the server. How does this provide that?

Comment: By simply getting the domain names of these machines and then checking if they are the same as the domain of his domain server ;-)

Comment: As I understand it this solution requires the remote machine to be switched on in order to run.  That's a potential drawback.

Comment: @Paul Matthews: Yes, thats right.